# Build yeoman project from git checkout

Tags: node.js, git, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Am facing issue in building the yeoman project checkout from git. Am trying to take git checkout of yeoman project and run **grunt serve**. Following is the scenario followed by error description

Scenario description :

**Person1** created the yeoman angularjs project using **yo angular**. **grunt serve** is working fine in **Person1**'s computer. **Person1** pushes the code to git so other team members can work on it.

Problem occurs when **Person2** takes a checkout of the git (**git clone < URL>**). The **grunt serve** command in the checked out copy will give following error :

```
$ grunt serve
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

I tried : `npm install grunt`

I got the following error :

```
grunt serve
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'load-grunt-tasks'
Warning: Task "serve" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Tools Used :

```
$ grunt -version
grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v0.4.4
$ yo -v
1.1.2
suraj@localhost:testing$ npm -version
1.4.4
```

ls -l on the directory

```
drwxrwxr-x app
-rw-rw-r-- bower.json
-rw-rw-r-- Gruntfile.js
-rw-rw-r-- karma.conf.js
-rw-rw-r-- karma-e2e.conf.js
drwxrwxr-x node_modules
-rw-rw-r-- package.json
drwxrwxr-x test
```

I need help in accomplishing the task of building the project from git checkout so I could carry on the development.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Execute a simple `npm install` inside the App-Directory.

The Problem is:
The Yeoman-Projcet has lots of npm-dependencies, not only grunt itself, but also all of grunts tasks and generators. But of course you wouldnt want all those packages inside your repository. Thats were the "package.json" File comes in: It Lists alls Packages the Project depents on. `npm install` reads the package.json and installs all needed packages by itself.

To run the app properly, you will also need to execute `bower install`.
Bower is for the Frontend-Packages what npm is for node. "bower install" looks for the dependent packages in the "bower.json"-File and installs them.

Comment: Thanks Charminbaer for explaining the commands. It helped to understand how yeoman manages dependencies. :)

Answer (score 6):

Solved in 2 steps. The the following commands :

1. **npm install**
2. **bower install**

Now run **grunt serve**

```
$ grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "bower-install:app" (bower-install) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

    Running "compass:server" (compass) task
    directory .tmp/styles/ 
       create .tmp/styles/main.css (8.454s)
    Compilation took 8.455s

    Done, without errors.


    Execution Time (2014-03-13 10:53:01 UTC)
    compass:server  9.1s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 100%
    Total 9.1s

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
Prefixed file ".tmp/styles/main.css" created.

Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Started connect web server on 127.0.0.1:9000.

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

This solves the problem.

Let me know if this can be avoided or done in better way :)