# node.js - grunt server doesn't start

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I'm using yeoman, grunt & bower all together for the first time.

Following this [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/kickstart-your-angularjs-development-with-yeoman-grunt-and-bower/) and I stuck up where I couldn't the server didn't start and was throwing me a error

```
WANRNING: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'c:\wamp\www\yo\app\bower.json'
```

And I found the solution for that error over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709324/grunt-wiredepapp-no-such-file-or-directory-bower-json) and now I'm not getting error.

---

But after fixing that error and I ran the `grunt serve` command. And started getting this error (fewer or rare)

```
Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
     Warning: Use --force to continue.

     Aborted due to warnings.
```

or this error (most occuring error)

```
Warning: grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13) Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.
```

If I run `grunt serve --force` of course it's running with a yellow text as

```
Warning:   Used --force, continuing.
```

Someone help me out to over come this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376185/build-yeoman-project-from-git-checkout).

Problem was the dependencies were not installed properly.

And by running

1. npm install
2. bower install

I was able to run the grunt serve without any errors.